# Connect touch event in ios

Tags: iphone, events

Now that I know that NSEvent does not exist on ios - what do I need to do to capture an event like touchUpInside and cause it to call my method to handle it, WITHOUT Interface Builder?

I think this like asking how do I link an event to an outlet without IB...

I know it can be done, but I can't find anything that shows how - except Mac-only examples that use NSEvent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this method in UIControl:

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents
```

Each of the different event types has a constant, such as UIControlEventTouchUpInside.  Here's an example of it being used:

```
[addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(increment:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

[Look here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for the values of controlEvents, listed in the Constants section.